# Google cloud, docker run fails with "no space left on device"

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to build and deploy a project in GCP. The build succeeds, but gives error when trying to run:

```
$ docker run us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/my-app/app/app-image:tag1
Unable to find image 'us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/my-app/app/app-image:tag1' locally
tag1: Pulling from my-app/app/app-image
918547b94326: Pulling fs layer 
5d79063a01c5: Pulling fs layer 
4eedd9c5abf7: Pulling fs layer 
9cdadd40055f: Pull complete 
2a12d0031f3f: Pull complete 
cea461a97d87: Pull complete 
a48c72dfa8c4: Pull complete 
c343b921680a: Pull complete 
a0703d5e5208: Pull complete 
a362037c8da4: Pull complete 
6a0783be9ccd: Pull complete 
c3e82ef8aa11: Extracting [==================================================>]  5.323GB/5.323GB
37c1cabf2396: Download complete 
4bb092176834: Download complete 
21b94b39e6d9: Download complete 
8b2c42abea6d: Download complete 
cb4dd3b4b8d1: Download complete 
ba886e62fb32: Download complete 
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_flax_bert.py: no space left on device.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

This is the output of `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.4
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.17.3
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 23.0.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc version: v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.107+
 Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) (containerized)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.63GiB
 Name: cs-930189570445-default
 ID: 5425103f-e34b-40eb-8c5a-825140a58c71
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: kristada673
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://asia-mirror.gcr.io/
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Its a new GCP account where this is the first project I'm trying to deploy, so there are no other images and so `docker prune` does not do anything.

This is the space left:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                             60G   47G   14G  78% /
tmpfs                               64M     0   64M   0% /dev
/dev/sda1                           60G   47G   14G  78% /root
/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1  4.8G   54M  4.5G   2% /home
/dev/root                          2.0G 1006M  952M  52% /usr/lib/modules
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              3.2G  1.3M  3.2G   1% /google/host/var/run
```

Is there a fixed size allocated to Docker images in GCP? If so, how do I increase the size of docker images in GCP?

Comment: If you've downloaded a 5+ GB compressed layer, and it needs to be unpacked before it can be used, I can in fact see that exceeding the 14 GB you have free in `/var/lib/docker`.

Comment: Where are you performing your docker run? On Cloud Shell?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes

Comment: @DavidMaze that's why I asked in the question if there's any limit to the docker size in GCP, and how to increase it.

Comment: the problem comes from Cloud Shell. You have 5Gb of free space on it. If your container is bigger than that, you can't run it on Cloud Shell. You have to start a Compute Engine if you want, you have a free tiers. With a compute engine, you will have a larger disk and no longer limitation

Comment: And running BERT on a shared CPU (with Cloud Shell) is not a very good idea!!

Comment: I am having the same problem which just happens today. In my my case, I was editing my  `docker-compose.yaml` file and I could not save it due to "no space left on device". Even after deleting some large files, the error remains. I don't think the actual culprit is due to no space on the device.

Comment: **Don't** use Cloud Shell for building Docker containers for production. Use **Google Cloud Build** or **GitHub Actions** within your GitHub repo, or use Compute instances with enough disk space for your workloads.